# Как работает загрузка файлов с mega.nz?

Tags: download, облако

Прошу прощения за, возможно, тривиальный вопрос.

Я не понимаю, как загружаются файлы с облачного сервиса mega.nz. Загрузка происходит как будто «на странице», там же виден прогресс, при этом вроде как перехватывается стандартная загрузка. А потом файл сразу целиком появляется в загрузках.

Как это сделано? Почему именно так?